# Dynamic segmented button in sencha touch

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I am working in a Sencha Touch application and I need to create a dynamic segmented button with different number of items from the controller instead of add to the view each time this component.

Correct way for this It should be create a singleton class and call to this when you need create the component... right?

Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`setItems`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Container-method-setItems):

> Sets the value of items.

For example:

```
segmentedButton.setItems([{text: 'Option 4'}, {text: 'Option 5'}])
```

Working example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1035

Comment: Thank you!!! it is working correctly for me, i was working around but .. now I am very glad!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Give id to button in view:

```
{
                    xtype: 'segmentedbutton',
                    allowToggle: false,
                    layout: {
                        type: 'hbox',
                        align: 'end'
                    },
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            id: 'btnStudents',
                            text: 'student'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            id: 'btnTeacher',
                            text: 'teacehr'
                        }
                    ]
                }
```

then in controller:

```
refs: {
        btnStudents: 'button#btnStudents',
        btnTeacher: 'button#btnTeacher',
    },
```

and depending on your requirement you can use:

```
this.getBtnStudents().show();
```

or `this.getBtnStudents().hide();`

Comment: thank for your response, but I want to add dynamically instead of show or hide items..